# How to add insecure Docker registry certificate to kubeadm config

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, bitnami, kubeadm

I'm quite new to Kubernetes, and I managed to get an Angular app deployed locally using minikube. But now I'm working on a [Bitnami Kubernetes Sandbox](https://bitnami.com/stack/kubernetes-sandbox/cloud) EC2 instance, and I've run into issues pulling from my docker registry on another EC2 instance.

Whenever I attempt to apply the deployment, the pods log the following error

```
Failed to pull image "registry-url.net:5000/app": no available registry endpoint:
failed to do request: Head https://registry-url.net/v2/app/manifests/latest:
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

The docker registry certificate **is** signed by a CA (Comodo RSA), but I had to add the registry's `.crt` and `.key` files to `/etc/docker/certs.d/registry-url.net:5000/` for my local copy of minikube and docker.

However, the Bitnami instance doesn't have an `/etc/docker/` directory and there is no `daemon.json` file to add insecure registry exceptions, and I'm not sure where the cert files are meant to be located for kubeadm.

**So is there a similar location to place `.crt` and `.key` files for kubeadm, or is there a command I can run to add my docker registry to a list of exceptions?**

*Or better yet, is there a way to get Kubernetes/docker to recognize the CA of the registry's SSL certs?*

Thanks

**Edit:** I've included my deployment and secret files below:

**app-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: registry-url.net:5000/app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            ...

      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-pull-secret
```

**registry-secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: registry-pull-secret
data:
 .dockerconfigjson: <base-64 JSON>
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving my issue by manually installing docker via the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Then I had to create the directory structure `/etc/docker/certs.d/registry-url:5000/` and copy the registry's `.crt` and `.key` files into the directory.

However, this still didn't work; but after stopping the EC2 instance and starting it again, it appears to pull from the remote registry with no issues.

When I initially ran `service kubelet restart` the changes didn't seem to take effect, but restarting did the trick. I'm not sure if there's a bettre way of fixing my issue, but this was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [`secret`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) with details for the repository.

This might be the example of uploading the image to your docker repo:

```
docker login _my-registry-url_:5000  
Username (admin):  
Password:  
Login Succeeded  

docker tag _user_/_my-cool-image_  _my-registry-url_:5000/_my-cool-image_:0.1  
docker push _my-registry-url_:5000/_my-cool-image_:0.1
```

From that host you should create the base64 of `~/.docker/config.json` like so
`cat ~/.docker/config.json | base64`
Then you will be able to add it to the secret, so create a `yaml` that might look like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: registrypullsecret
data:
 .dockerconfigjson: <base-64-encoded-json-here>
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Once done you can apply the secret using `kubectl create -f my-secret.yaml && kubectl get secrets`.

As for your `pod` it should look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: jss
spec:
 imagePullSecrets:
  — name: registrypullsecret
 containers:
  — name: jss
    image: my-registry-url:5000/my-cool-image:0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I think this is the right direction I have to take. I'll try this tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: So I created the secret yaml file and updated the Deployment accordingly, but I still get the same error. The problem is that the registry is still not trusted. I've also updated my question with the new deployment + secret files.

Comment: Please take a look for [Private Registry Authentication for Container Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth-container-instances.html)